# Module not recognised in ipython when trying to run python-twitter API (CS109)

Tags: python, twitter, ipython, installation-path

How do I get the twitter API to work in the case below? Is this problem happening because I'm accidentally using the wrong module. And if so, how do I fix it?

I've been doing Harvard's CS109, Lecture 1 ipython notebook - all the other examples worked for me, except this one.  Everything was installed months ago using anaconda.  I think I'm having trouble getting ipython to use the correct library.

I've typed this in ipython:

```
!pip install python-twitter //I added this later to try to identify where it was breaking
!pip install twitter //I added this later to try to identify where it was breaking

import twitter
print twitter //I added this later to help to identify where it was breaking

## define the necessary keys
cKey = "<myKeyIsHere>"
cSecret =  "<mySecretIsHere>"
aKey = "<myAccessKeyIsHere>"
aSecret = "<myAccessSecretIsHere>"

## create the api object with the twitter-python library
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=cKey, consumer_secret=cSecret, access_token_key=aKey, access_token_secret=aSecret)
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-twitter in /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-twitter)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests-oauthlib in /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-twitter)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): oauthlib>=0.6.2 in /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib->python-twitter)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter in /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<module 'twitter' from '/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter/__init__.pyc'>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-8bddd9593b3f> in <module>()
     10 
     11 ## create the api object with the twitter-python library
---> 12 api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=cKey, consumer_secret=cSecret, access_token_key=aKey, access_token_secret=aSecret)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

So far, I've done the following actions:

1. I had exactly the same error (though none of the install messages) when I started. Initially, I figured the error was thrown because I didn't have the proper library installed.  From terminal, I ran 'pip install twitter', which didn't fix it because ... I don't think it's the right library.  I was supposed to be using python-twitter.  I had misunderstood what the error was.  I have since run 'pip uninstall twitter', discovered there's a dependency between it and python-twitter, and reinstalled it via ipython.
2. I used 'which' in terminal to check that my python and ipython are in the same location - they are.
3. Back in ipython I used 'print twitter' just after 'import twitter' in order to see which object ipython was referencing.  It showed me a twitter package, not a python-twitter package.
4. I'd been reading stackoverflow and found answers that suggested I might have confused ipython by running the 'pip install twitter' and 'pip uninstall twitter' and thought I must have been somehow using different installations.
5. To figure that out, and ensure I was in the right location and couldn't be misusing it, from ipython I ran '!pip install python-twitter' and '!pip install twitter'.  I'm reasoning that they're properly installed because the messages say the requirements are already satisfied, and they're all in the anaconda installation.  Is that right?

I think that if my ipython was using the correct library that my module object would have an 'Api' method because the docs for python-twitter (https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) have this example:

```
  >>> import twitter
  >>> api = twitter.Api()
```

If anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.